# How do I get the case insensitive match in List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have a list of words in a List. Using .Contains(), I can determine if a word is in the list. If a word I specify is in the list, how do I get the case sensitive spelling of the word from the list? For example, .Contains() is true when the word is "sodium phosphate" but the list contains "Sodium Phosphate". How do I perform a case-insensitive search ("sodium phosphate") yet return the case-sensitive match ("Sodium Phosphate") from the list?

I prefer to avoid a dictionary where the key is uppercase and the value is proper cased, or vice verse.

Comment: Side notes: your title says "case sensitive", but it looks like you are looking for opposite. Also any particular reason to *not* use Dictionary with case insensitive key match?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well, using a dictionary would result in tripling the memory footprint of the program instead of using the more appropriate (in this context) searching method.

Comment: @Servy, argee, but not using linear search through the list may be useful - it is not completely clear for me from the question if unordered list is the requirement.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The dictionary wouldn't be in place of the linear search through the list, it would be *in addition to*, which is what makes it such a loss.  He was thinking of something like `if(list.Contains(searchText, invariantComparer)) return caseLookup[searchText];`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You want something like:

```
string match = list.FirstOrDefault(element => element.Equals(target, 
                                     StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

This will leave `match` as a `null` reference if no match can be found.

(You could use [`List<T>.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx), but using `FirstOrDefault` makes the code more general, as it will work - with a `using System.Linq;` directive at the top of the file) on *any* sequence of strings.)

Note that I'm assuming there are no null elements in the list. If you want to handle that, you may want to use a static method call instead: `string.Equals(element, target, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)`.

Also note that I'm assuming you want a culture-sensitive comparison. See [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) for other options.

Comment: out of curiousity, why not `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`?

Comment: +1 While this is absolutely correct answer to the question, note that linear search through an unordered list is not the fastest operation - building list of 100s items this way may easily turn into a problem.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov A few hundred wouldn't be a problem at all.  You'd need hundreds of thousands to really be much of an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Consider if [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx) with case insensitive comparison work for you. Unless you care about order of words `Dictionary` will give you much better performance of look up than list.

```
Dictionary<string, string> openWith = 
      new Dictionary<string, string>( 
         StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `StringComparer` in list

```
if (listOfValues.Contains(value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```